# Can I mount a S3 bucket mounted to Linux EC2 to a Windows EC2 with Samba(smb)?

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, samba, s3fs

I have a situation where in I have to mount AWS S3 bucket to a Linux EC2 instance(Linux) using FUSE([S3FS](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse)).

Once the Bucket it mounted, it need to be mounted in an Windows EC2 instance with Samba([smb](https://www.samba.org/)).
I am able to mount the S3 bucket to the Linux EC2 instance using FUSE (S3FS),
but while trying to change content for Samba mount I get the  below error:

```
[centos@sharedfs-23-117 /]$ sudo chcon -t samba_share_t /s3fs-ed/
chcon: failed to change context of ‘/s3fs-ed/’ to ‘system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0’: Operation not supported.
```

**Note**: My S3 bucket is mounted on /s3fs-ed.

**Observation**: df -h List all the mounts including the S3 mount:

```
[centos@sharedfs-23-117 /]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        472M     0  472M   0% /dev
tmpfs           493M  240K  493M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           493M   13M  480M   3% /run
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  1.1G  7.0G  13% /
/dev/xvdb1      8.0G  574M  7.5G   8% /store
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
s3fs            256T     0  256T   0% /s3fs-ed
```

But When I try to list the disk by UUID, I do not see the S3 mount being listed:

```
[centos@sharedfs-23-117 /]$ ls -lha /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  80 Jul 16 09:07 .
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 100 Jul 16 09:07 ..
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  11 Jul 16 09:07 388a99ed-9486-4a46-aeb6-06eaf6c47675 -> ../../xvda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  11 Jul 16 09:07 fce0d14e-24c6-4f69-b04b-b80041cd636f -> ../../xvdb1
```

I need help to mount the S3 mount using Samba to the Windows EC2 instance.

**Note** : Due to some limitation I cannot mount S3 to Windows with rclone (https://rclone.org/).

I have tried disabling the SELinux also , Still the same error

```
[centos@sharedfs-23-117 /]$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Comment: I believe that Samba uses extended attributes for some metadata.  Can you remount s3fs with `-o use_xattr`?

Answer (score 0):

I mount a bucket with s3fs with the following command:

```
s3fs bucketname /mnt/s3/ -o passwd_file=/etc/.passwd-s3fs -o umask=0000 -o allow_other -o kernel_cache
```

And I share the folder /mnt/s3 with samba with no problems.

I you still have trouble, share your s3fs mount command, and the smb.conf section you use to share the mount point.